# Google Sheets' conditional formatting of a range based on the age of cells in that range, but only if another cell out of that range is blank

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet containing vendor invoice information with the following column headers:

- Supplier
- Invoice Date
- Invoice Number
- $ Amount
- Employee Name
- Job Name/#
- Employee Date Paid

What I would like to do is show a colour or range of colours in the Invoice Date column based on how far away that date is from today (like a coloured expiration guide), but only if the corresponding cell in Employee Date Paid is blank. The custom formula option in conditional formatting is a touch beyond me to get it started. I am comfortable modifying existing formulae for behaviours and colours and what not, but don't know where to start with this.

- *sorry if this doesn't format correctly and shows up as a paragraph, still learning the format rules...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe better suited to [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and a shame no mention of what is where but given *I am comfortable modifying existing formulae* I suggest:

Select Column B, Format - Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is and:

```
=and(G1="",B1<today()-60,B1<>"")
```

with one formatting of your choice and Add another rule:

```
=and(G1="",B1>today()-30,B1<today(),B1<>"")
```

with another. <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Worked like a charm. I posted here because I saw other Google Sheets questions on this Stack. I will do a better job of posting in the future. Thank you for your help.